# почему после события клика в div меняется data-type с save на edit , а программа видить только который был загружен изначально?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.language_level').click(function(){
   var parent_block = $(this).closest( ".language-block" );
   
   var type = parent_block.data('type');
   if (type === 'save') {
         parent_block.attr('data-type','edit');
   }//Посмотреть в барузере меняется на  edit
    
   console.log(type);//save
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group  language-block col-md-12 " data-profile_id="{{$dataTypeContent->id}}" data-type="save">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input class="language_level languages" data-language_id="{{$language->id}}" type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="">
            <label class="lang-label" for="language_{{$language->id}}">{{$language->title}}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="1" checked="" disabled>
          <label for="">1</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="2" disabled >
          <label for="">2</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="3" disabled>
          <label for="">3</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="4" disabled>
          <label for="">4</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="5" disabled>
          <label for="">5</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="6" disabled>
          <label for="">6</label>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Я не понял что вы хотите сделать? И какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: после того как чекбокс выбран этот блок должен стать edit чтобы при следующем клике к примеру на изменение level программа знала что это нужно отправить на update

Comment: когда чекбокс снять или изменить level должен писать edit а не save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже jQuery сохраняет в память все значения с атрибутов **data**, поэтому при изменении через **attr**, в **data** будет старое значение, так что вам надо либо и получать значение также через **attr**, либо использовать везде **data**

```js
$('.language_level').click(function(){
   var parent_block = $(this).closest( ".language-block" );
   var type = parent_block.data('type');
   
   if (type == 'save') {
       parent_block.data('type','edit');
   }
   
    
   console.log(type);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group  language-block col-md-12 " data-profile_id="{{$dataTypeContent->id}}" data-type="save">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input class="language_level languages" data-language_id="{{$language->id}}" type="checkbox" name="language[]" value="">
            <label class="lang-label" for="language_{{$language->id}}">{{$language->title}}</label>
        </div>

        <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="1" checked="" disabled>
          <label for="">1</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="2" disabled >
          <label for="">2</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="3" disabled>
          <label for="">3</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="4" disabled>
          <label for="">4</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="5" disabled>
          <label for="">5</label>
       </div>
       <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
          <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="6" disabled>
          <label for="">6</label>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нет смысла в использовании **Jquery**, так как кода и так мало. Можно было бы ещё и сеттеры с геттерами заюзать...

```js
// Элемент
const checkbox_element = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"].languages');

// Чтобы не было магического текста
const EDIT = 'edit';
const SAVE = 'save';

// Функция установки значения, хотя я бы оперировал булевым значением
const setFlag = value => value ? EDIT : SAVE;

// Будет вызываться по клику на чекбокс. Пробегается по всем радио и либо блокирует либо наоборот
const updateDisabled = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"].language_level').forEach(el => el.disabled = flag === SAVE);
};

// Инициализируем значение
let flag = setFlag(checkbox_element.checked);

// Навешиваем событие
checkbox_element.addEventListener('click', function() {
  flag = setFlag(this.checked);

  updateDisabled();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group  language-block col-md-12 " data-profile_id="{{$dataTypeContent->id}}" data-type="save">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input class="language_level languages" data-language_id="{{$language->id}}" type="checkbox" name="language[]">
    <label class="lang-label" for="language_{{$language->id}}">{{$language->title}}</label>
  </div>

  <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="1" checked="" disabled>
    <label for="">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="2" disabled>
    <label for="">2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="3" disabled>
    <label for="">3</label>
  </div>
  <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="4" disabled>
    <label for="">4</label>
  </div>
  <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="5" disabled>
    <label for="">5</label>
  </div>
  <div class="lang-radio col-md-1">
    <input type="radio" id="" class="language_level" name="lang-level-{{$language->id}}" value="6" disabled>
    <label for="">6</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, просто jquery уже стоит всеравно

можно вас еще спросить по поводу update , save уже разобрался,

когда приходит на update ведь тут же схема отличается  как на save, я же не знаю id это строки
LanguageLevel чтобы обновить

Comment: или нужно получить обьекст зная profile_id а потом его updated ?

Comment: если просто так
 
        $language_level =  new LanguageLevel;
        
        $language_level->update(['language_id' => $language_id, 'level_id' => $level_id]);

то в таблице может же быть несколько таких же строк относящихся к другитм профилям

Comment: @Junior если вы про предыдущий вопрос, то да. проверять лучше всегда)

Comment: я имею ввиду
public function update(Request $request) {
        
        $profile_id = $request->profile_id; 
        $language_id = $request->language_id; 
        $level_id = $request->level_id;
         
        $language_level =  new LanguageLevel;
        
        $language_level->update(['language_id' => $language_id, 'level_id' => $level_id]);
    }

как знать что эта именно та строка которая обновляется?

Comment: @Junior я понял. Всегда надо проверять.

Comment: так в том то и вопрос? как)

Comment: если бы в этой эе ьаблице было profile id то можно было бы через $language_level->where(profile_id)->update(['language_id' => $language_id, 'level_id' => $level_id]);
а так то нет там

Comment: @Junior я ж вам в вопросе отвечал. `App\Profile::with('languages.language')->find($request->profil_id);` дальше по коллекции пробегитесь и посмотрите, есть ли id языка у пользователя.

Comment: а вот так я сделал правильно?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154898/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86-laravel    в ответе