# как обновить данные связанных таблиц? Laravel

Tags: laravel

Я так понимаю что нужно обновить данные из таблицы :language_levels строка то остается и ее id , который является language_level_id в таблице profile_languages соответственно в profile_languages менять не нужно, а только в language_levels и только поле level_id
так как профиль profile_id остается тот же и строка в language_level_id

class LanguageLevelController extends Controller
{
public function update(Request $request) {

```
        $profile_id = $request->profile_id;
        $language_id = $request->language_id; 
        $level_id = $request->level_id;
        
        //тут что-то не то не работает
        $profile = Profile::where('id', $profile_id)->get();
        $profile->languages->language->update(['language_id' => $language_id]);
        $profile->languages->level->update(['level_id' => $level_id]);
      
    }
}

class Profile extends Model
{
public function profile_languages(){
      return $this->hasMany(ProfileLanguage::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return HasManyThrough
     */
    public function languages(){
      return $this->HasManyThrough(LanguageLevel::class,ProfileLanguage::class,  'profile_id', 'id', 'id', 'language_level_id');
    }
}

class LanguageLevel extends Model
{
   /**
   * @return HasOne
   */
  public function language(){
    return $this->HasOne(Language::class, 'id', 'language_id');
  }

  /**
   * @return HasOne
   */
  public function level(){
    return $this->HasOne(Level::class, 'id', 'level_id');
  }

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

спасибо!!

Answer (score 0):

как считаете такая нормальная конструкция? Работает зато)

```
public function update(Request $request) {
        
        $profile_id = $request->profile_id;
        $language_id = $request->language_id; 
        $level_id = $request->level_id;
              
        $profile = Profile::where('id', $profile_id)->first();
        $profile_languages_ids = $profile->profile_languages->pluck('language_level_id');
        
        foreach ($profile_languages_ids as $profile_languages_id){
            
            LanguageLevel::where('id', $profile_languages_id)->where('language_id', $language_id)->update(['language_id'=>$language_id, 'level_id'=>$level_id]);
        }
        
    }
```